# Наиболее популярные видео в youtube, по ключевым словам и без

Tags: youtube

Как получить список youtube-видео с определенными ключевыми словами, отсортированный по просмотрам?
А также,
можно ли получить список наиболее популярных youtube-видео на определенном языке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска по ключевым словам:

1. Пишем нужные слова в поисковом окне YouTube-а
2. Нажимаем на кнопку поиска
3. Теперь под поисковым окном появляется фильтр.
   Заходим в него и выбираем `Упорядочить` ->  `По числу просмотров`
   При желании можно также поменять `По дате загрузки`.
4. Еще раз нажимаем кнопку поиска.

Вуаля!
Тут надо отметить, что YouTube глючит и часть результатов первоначального поиска по словам выбрасывает после сортировки. Кроме того, сортировка не очень точная.

А как найти наиболее популярные видео на каком-то языке?
Насколько я понимаю, YouTube не дает простым людям искать регулярные выражения, наверно для этого нужно использовать API.